# Some rounding algorithms support in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, math

I need to use some rounding algorithms, from my c# application:

*systematic*:

[image]

*random*:

[image]

and *controlled*:

[image]

Does .NET Framework provide math support for this algorithms (maybe there any free libraries available for c#) or I need to implement this functions on my own ? How can I check correctness of the algorithms if I implement them, to be sure they are right ? Does anyone have sample input and output data for it ? Are there any free applications I can compare my calculated results for sample input with ?

Comment: @AlexandreC, please qualify any such statements you make, if you can. This is not a forum to simply let opinion loose.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [these](http://www.pennedobjects.com/2010/05/adventures-in-net-rounding-part-1-the-mystery-of-math-round/) articles can serve as a starting point?

1. [Adventures in .NET Rounding Part 1: The Mystery of Math.Round](http://www.pennedobjects.com/2010/05/adventures-in-net-rounding-part-1-the-mystery-of-math-round/)
2. [Adventures in .NET Rounding Part 2: Exotic Rounding Algorithms](http://www.pennedobjects.com/2010/06/adventures-in-net-rounding-part-2-exotic-rounding-algorithms/)
3. [Adventures in .NET Rounding Part 3: Rounding in Action](http://www.pennedobjects.com/2010/06/adventures-in-net-rounding-part-3-rounding-in-action/)

Comment: I feel like you are simply correlating "rounding" with some articles you googled without verifying that these articles have anything to do with the algorithms that the OP is looking for.

Comment: Which is why I said "starting point". The OP is free to disregard my answer if he so chooses. Those articles were, in fact useful to me when I encountered a similar problem last year.

Comment: Oh, and just to prove that this wasn't a "random" Google result - note that "Random rounding" the OP is talking about looks a lot like "RoundDither" to me.